# Sum of multiple arrays in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel-blade

I have 5 arrays, each array contains `medicine_price`, `medicine_quantity`. What i want is to add the result of each array. The problem is , i cant get the correct result of each array.

Example:

```
Array 1: result1 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

Array 2: result2 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

Array 3: result3 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

Array 4: result4 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

Array 5: result5 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

total = result1 + result2 + result3 + result4 + result5
```

This should be the result that i want . And it is also possible that more array will be included since i have incremented them.

Code :

```
@php
    $i = 1;
    @endphp
    @foreach($carts as $cart)


    {!! $cart->medicine_quantity !!}

    @php
    $value=  $cart->medicine_price  * $cart->medicine_quantity;
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='sample$i' value='$value'>";

    $i++
    @endphp

    @endforeach



    @php
    echo "$Total_price"
    @endphp
```

Comment: did you mean to tag this as **javascript** ?

Comment: add `$Total_price = 0;` after `$i=0;` and do `$Total_price += $value;` after `$value=  $cart->medicine_price  * $cart->medicine_quantity;`

Comment: Yes , i forgot to tag it as javascript i apologize . @gkelly

Comment: There's any compelling reason for not doing it on the controller/service side?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
@php
    $totalPrice = 0;
@endphp

@foreach($carts as $key => $cart)

    {!! $cart->medicine_quantity !!}

    @php
        $value = $cart->medicine_price  * $cart->medicine_quantity;
        $totalPrice += $value;
    @endphp

    <input type='hidden' id='sample{{ $key + 1 }}' value='{{ $value }}'>

@endforeach

Total price: {{ $totalPrice }}
```

Hope this helps!